# Eclipse Android: My app is upside down only on 10"-Tablets. Why?

Tags: android, eclipse

I only use the portrait-modus for my app. My app works properly on all devices. Only on 10"-Tablets it is upside down. How can this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"` instead of `android:screenOrientation="Portrait"`.

Comment: That works. Do I have to change s.th. in my code too?

Comment: s.th ? Not getting what you are saying?

Comment: s.o. told me if I use SensorPortrait my activity starts everythime new when I change between portrait and landscape. It might crush down then. So I have to write in my code, that the activity shouldn't start again if I rotate the tablet/phone ?!

Comment: add this line to your activity in manifest  android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboardHidden" . it will stop the recreation of your activity.